# Why my RecyclerViewAdapter messing up the element's indexes?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a functionality of adding elements to RecyclerViewAdapter. Everything seems to be working, but at some point a weird thing happens: starting with the index 2, RVA adds new element at the beggining of the RecyclerView. Why does this happen?

I've tried to add elements at certaing index with the help of a 
   arrayList.add(index, element), but it wasn't a success.

AddBigTaskFragment.class

```
public class AddBigTaskFragment extends Fragment  {
...
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RVABigTask adapter;
private ArrayList<SubTask> arrayList;
...
public AddBigTaskFragment() {
}

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_big_task, container, false);

    ...

    adapter = new RVABigTask(getContext());
    adapter.setListener(this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    close_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> getFragmentManager().popBackStack());

    rl_add.setOnClickListener(v -> adapter.addToRV()); //Adding the element to adapter

public void refreshAdapterOnAdd(int position) {        
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void refreshAdapterOnDelete(int position) {
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
}
```

RVABigTask.class

```
public class RVABigTask extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVABigTask.ViewHolder>{

private Context context;
...
private ArrayList<SubTask> arrayList;
private AddBigTaskFragment fragment;
private DataManager dataManager;
private int index = 0;

public RVABigTask(Context context ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.iAdapterRefresher = iAdapterRefresher;
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    RVABigTask.ViewHolder vh = new RVABigTask.ViewHolder(v);
    dataManager = new DataManager(context, null);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SubTask item = arrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

    if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
        fragment.save_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (arrayList.size() <= 0) {
        fragment.save_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (holder.recycler_edittext.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
    {
        holder.recycler_edittext.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }

...

    holder.delete_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> removeAt(position, item));
}

public void addToRV() {
    SubTask subTask = new SubTask();
    arrayList.add(subTask);
    refreshItems(arrayList);
    index++;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
        return arrayList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public ArrayList<SubTask> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

public void setListener(AddBigTaskFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void removeAt(int position, SubTask subTask) {
    arrayList.remove(position);
//arrayList.remove(subTask);
    fragment.refreshAdapterOnDelete(position);
}

public void setSubTasksReference(String reference) {
    for (SubTask subTask : arrayList) {
        subTask.setReference(reference);
        dataManager.addSubTask(subTask);
    }
}

private void refreshItems(ArrayList<SubTask> array) {
    ArrayList<SubTask> secondary = new ArrayList<>();
    secondary.addAll(array);
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.addAll(secondary);
    fragment.refreshAdapterOnAdd(index);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public EditText recycler_edittext;
    public ImageButton delete_btn;
    public CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recycler_edittext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_edittext);
        delete_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_item_recycler);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_recycler);
    }
}
}
```

I expected the RecyclerView to be like "1 - 2 - 3", but I got this:
1)Adding 1 element, everything's ok
2)Adding 2 element, still ok, recycler looks like this: "1 - 2"
3)Adding 3 element, and order is messed up: "3 - 1 - 2"

I don't really know what to do :(

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder` the `SubTask item = arrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());` uses the position retrieved from the `holder` object but may use the `position` parameter instead. However in the shown code, the `item` is not used for filling the view.

Comment: @MichaelButscher You're absolutely right, I've changed `position` to `getAdapterPosition()`, just to try out and see whether it's helpful. But it's not. The thing is that I cleared some parts of a code, which are not correspondent to the question, but actually I use the `item` in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I reviewed my code again, and you were absolutely right. `arrayList` wasn't, to say, "bound" to `RecyclerView`. And I haven't noticed it. So thank you very much!